# Test phonegap iphone app created using distribution keys

Tags: ios, iphone, cordova, phonegap-build, ad-hoc-distribution

I have created an app using phonegap and build it with phonegap build and tested and working fine. 
I created new ipa file using distribution keys and tried to test that one on an iphone. But it is showing that "could not be installed at this time" . Actually is it possible to test an app which is created using distribution keys on an iphone?

Comment: If it is signed with your store distribution keys then no there is no way except to resign it with a different key.

Comment: Did you mean that I can test an app which is created with development keys only?. App created using distribution keys can be available from app store after the deployment.

Comment: That's correct.  You can only submit using distribution keys for the store.  You cannot deploy it to any device on your own.

Comment: You can upload the app to itunes connect and test it with the testflight app before you release it